# SQLite UNIQUE Exceptions handling JAVA

Tags: java, sqlite, exception

First of all I'm a begginer so please chill guyz. I'd like to create an app which allow us to get every one NOT UNIQUE row from first sqlite Table and place it to another table. So if the row already exist in the second table the program should increment index of row's ID. I mean sth like this e.g.

```
for(int i=0, i<10,i++){
  query = "Select * from table where ID="+i;
  executeQuery(query);
}
```

If the query cannot be executed I'm getting an exception like this one:

```
java.sql.SQLException :UNIQUE constraint failed: NewTableAUi.PHONE
```

I've got a little problem with catching an exception while the row I wanna insert is already exist. Thanks for all feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you are getting an exception, that means you need to handle it. Upon the query execution do something like this:

```
try {
     //your query code

} catch (SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("Exception Message");

}
```